# how to write a query to fetch record in laravel? using roles

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, laravel

I want if order taker is login then get areas of his own created and his admin created(with role = 1) or sub-admin(with role = 2) in $areas

i have 3 table: (1.users 2.areas 3.ordertaker)
i have 3 roles: (1.admin 2. sub-admin 3. ordertaker)

admin and sub-admin can create (order taker and area)
order taker can also create (area)

every order taker is associated with ot_of in the user table (for admin(id) and sub-admin(id))

every Area is associated with created_by

steps we need to perform the first check which order taker  is login

```
if(Auth::user()->role == 1 ){
either ot_of (admin(ordertaker) role = 1 or subadmin(ordertaker) role = 2)
if{
then get area if ot_of belongs to admin then get both area created_by(ordertaker and admin)  
}else
{
then get area if ot_of belongs to sub-admin then get both area created_by(order taker and sub-admin)  

}
}
```

how I can write this query every person is uniquely identifying with a unique id
now i am getting areas using this code

```
 $idss = [Auth::id()];
        if (Auth::user()->role < 3) {
            $idss = array_merge($idss, User::where('ot_of', Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray());
        }
        $fitered_area = Area::all();
        $allareas = $fitered_area->whereIn('created_by', $idss);
```

but problem is that if ordertaker is login he can not have access to his admin areas because he did not created it

Answer (score 0):

If i may suggest a more dynamic solution to your problem, check this out [Laravel Permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Hardcoding roles and permissions in this way, will get tangled really fast.